# Decrypt result of Java Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding") failed with OpenResty's resty.aes module

Tags: java, nginx, encryption, lua

I'm developing an nginx(openresty) Lua module, and one of the requirements is to decipher an encrypted string generated by a legacy Java program. But my Lua code failed to decipher it and I'm looking for help here.

Java encryption and decryption code which is ok:

```
public class AesCbc {
    private static String PLAIN = "usr/passwd@bizdb:127.0.0.1:5432";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("1234567890ABCDEF".getBytes(), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("fedcba0987654321".getBytes());

        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv);
        byte[] rawBytes = PLAIN.getBytes();
        byte[] aligned;
        int mod = rawBytes.length % 16; // prevent javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
        if (mod == 0) {
            aligned = new byte[rawBytes.length];
        } else {
            aligned = new byte[rawBytes.length + 16 - mod];
        }
        System.arraycopy(rawBytes, 0, aligned, 0, rawBytes.length);
        byte[] cipherBytes = aesCipher.doFinal(aligned);
        String base64Result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherBytes);
        System.out.println("cipher:[" + base64Result + "], rawBytes.length=" + rawBytes.length + ", mod=" + mod);

        aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv);
        cipherBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Result);
        aligned = aesCipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
        int posNil;
        for (posNil = 0; posNil < aligned.length; posNil++) {
            if (aligned[posNil] == 0x00)
                break;
        }
        rawBytes = new byte[posNil];
        System.arraycopy(aligned, 0, rawBytes, 0, posNil);
        String plain = new String(rawBytes);
        System.out.println("plain:[" + plain + "], posNil=" + posNil + ", aligned.length=" + aligned.length);
    }
}
```

Output of the Java code:

```
cipher:[l1buytGEL4RKa/RezInQ3dJxvMtL6nyE2wTi7VyoS4w=], rawBytes.length=31, mod=15
plain:[usr/passwd@bizdb:127.0.0.1:5432], posNil=31, aligned.length=32
```

My Lua test file declared within nginx.conf->http->server section:

```
            location /aescbc {
                    content_by_lua_file conf/aescbc.lua;
            }
```

Content of conf/aescbc.lua:

```
-- aescbc.lua

local aes = require "resty.aes"
local str = require "resty.string"
local aes128Cbc = aes:new("1234567890ABCDEF", nil, aes.cipher(128, "cbc"), {iv="fedcba0987654321"})

-- result of AesCbc.java for my test
local BASE64CIPHER = "l1buytGEL4RKa/RezInQ3dJxvMtL6nyE2wTi7VyoS4w="

local cipherBytes = ngx.decode_base64(BASE64CIPHER)
if not cipherBytes then
    ngx.log(ngx.WARN, "decode base64 [" .. BASE64CIPHER .. "] failed")
    return
end

local aligned = aes128Cbc:decrypt(cipherBytes)
if not aligned then
    ngx.log(ngx.WARN, "decrypt cipherBytes [" .. str.to_hex(cipherBytes) .. "] failed")
    return
end

ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, "aligned [" .. str.to_hex(aligned) .. "]")
return
```

When testing with "curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/aescbc", the nginx error log:

```
2017/08/03 11:28:26 [warn] 13799#0: *5 [lua] aescbc.lua:18: decrypt cipherBytes [9756eecad1842f844a6bf45ecc89d0ddd271bccb4bea7c84db04e2ed5ca84b8c] failed, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /aescbc HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
```

I think there must be something wrong with my usage of resty.aes, but how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

After searching the web, reading man pages and struggling some experiments for a few days, the problem is solved. So I answer it myself:

The resty.aes module uses OpenSSL's default PKCS7 padding algorithm, and there is no method to set *NoPadding* option in the current version of resty.aes. So I did a patch to it: (add a *padding* parameter and call *EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding()* in aes:new)

```
$ diff ./lualib/resty/aes.lua.orig ./lualib/resty/aes.lua
79a80
> int EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *x, int padding);
128c129
< function _M.new(self, key, salt, _cipher, _hash, hash_rounds)
---
> function _M.new(self, key, salt, _cipher, _hash, hash_rounds, padding)
177a179,184
>     end
> 
>     if padding then
>         -- 0:NoPadding, 1:PKCS7(default), 2:ISO7816_4, 3:ANSI923, 4:ISO10126, 5:ZERO
>         C.EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(encrypt_ctx, padding);
>         C.EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(decrypt_ctx, padding);
```

And did some minor modifications to the lua test code:

```
$ cat ./nginx/conf/aescbc.lua 
-- aescbc.lua

local aes = require "resty.aes"
local str = require "resty.string"
local aes128Cbc = aes:new("1234567890ABCDEF", nil, aes.cipher(128, "cbc"), {iv="fedcba0987654321"}, nil, 0)

-- result of AesCbc.java for my test
local BASE64CIPHER = "l1buytGEL4RKa/RezInQ3dJxvMtL6nyE2wTi7VyoS4w="

local cipherBytes = ngx.decode_base64(BASE64CIPHER)
if not cipherBytes then
    ngx.log(ngx.WARN, "decode base64 [" .. BASE64CIPHER .. "] failed")
    return
end

local aligned = aes128Cbc:decrypt(cipherBytes)
if not aligned then
    ngx.log(ngx.WARN, "decrypt cipherBytes [" .. str.to_hex(cipherBytes) .. "] failed")
    return
end

ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, "aligned [" .. str.to_hex(aligned) .. "], len=" .. aligned:len())

local plain 
local idx = aligned:find('\0')
if idx then
    plain = aligned:sub(1, idx - 1)
else
    plain = aligned
end

ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, "plain [" .. plain .. "], len=" .. plain:len())

return
```

The nginx err log for the test:

```
2017/08/07 15:17:55 [notice] 34632#0: *21 [lua] aescbc.lua:22: aligned [7573722f7061737377644062697a64623a3132372e302e302e313a3534333200], len=32, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /aescbc HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
2017/08/07 15:17:55 [notice] 34632#0: *21 [lua] aescbc.lua:32: plain [usr/passwd@bizdb:127.0.0.1:5432], len=31, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /aescbc HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem but encryption happens in a .NET application. I wonder if you can share the full version of the aes.lua patch, from your answer I don't understand where the 'C.EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding' calls are located in the lua file. Regards.